# OpenGL 2D rotation problem

Tags: opengl, transformation, matrix-multiplication, glrotate

In the following program i am trying to draw a simple house. The coordinates are defined in the house array. I need to rotate the house and display both rotated as well as the original house. 
But why is the rotated house not being displayed?

```
    //Program to create a house like figure and rotate ir about a given fixed point using OpenGL functions.
#include <glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float house [11][2] = {{100,200},{200,250},{300,200},{100,200},{100,100},{175,100},{175,150},{225,150},{225,100},{300,100},{300,200}};

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0,800,0,800);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //NORMAL HOUSE
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        glVertex2fv(house[i]);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();


    //ROTATED HOUSE
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(60,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        glVertex2fv(house[i]);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("House rotation");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rotating on the Z axis instead of the Y axis:

```
//Program to create a house like figure and rotate ir about a given fixed point using OpenGL functions.
#include <GL/glut.h>

float house [11][2] = {{100,200},{200,250},{300,200},{100,200},{100,100},{175,100},{175,150},{225,150},{225,100},{300,100},{300,200}};

void display()
{
    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,800,0,800);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //NORMAL HOUSE
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        glVertex2fv(house[i]);
    glEnd();


    //ROTATED HOUSE
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(100,100,0);
    glRotatef(60,0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(-100,-100,0);
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
        glVertex2fv(house[i]);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("House rotation");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

EDIT: This one should rotate around the bottom corner.

Comment: The above modification displays the output. But it doesnot rotate the house about its bottom left corner which is at 100,100. So i tried this:
glTranslatef(-100,-100,0);
glRotatef(30,0,0,1);
glTranslatef(100,100,0);

But stil it doesnt work. Why?

Comment: @footy: Edited.  Looks like those transforms were in the wrong order.